# Rise of the Triad in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: games

I noticed that "rott" is in the repository so I installed it via Synaptic. I created `/usr/share/games/rott` and copied these files in:

darkwar.rtl
  darkwar.wad
  remote1.rts

From the full registered version, however when I try to run the game I get the following messages:

```
Rise of the Triad Startup  Version 1.4  
Shareware Version     
Z_INIT: 8950000 bytes  
IN_Startup: Mouse Present  
Error, Could not find User file '/usr/share/games/rott/HUNTBGIN.WAD', ignoring file     
Adding /usr/share/games/rott/REMOTE1.RTS.  
W_Wad: Wad Manager Started NUMLUMPS=12  
W_GetNumForName: tables not found! Episode = 0  
Area = 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, found my answer.  I need to start the game with "rott-commercial" not "rott."  I need to update the .desktop file to invoke it correctly.

Comment: You can invoke `sudo update-alternatives --config rott` and select the commercial version to make it the default.